# errors when running Eclipse from a user terminal, but not from root

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I had eclipse installed (well, unpacked) under my home dir (`~/eclipse`) and it worked ok (well, as much as you can say it about eclipse). Today it went totally crazy, throwing "stack overflow" errors all the time. (BTW, did you know it is completely impossible to google for "stack overflow" problems these days? Guess what you get... :)

So I downloaded the latest version and installed it under `/opt/eclipse` this time. When trying to run it from my user terminal I get loads of errors:

> (eclipse:28336): GLib-GObject-WARNING
>   **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
>
> (eclipse:28336): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL
>   **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)'
>   failed
>
> (eclipse:28336): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (eclipse:28336): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow
>   before using the window
>
> etc. etc.

Running it from root terminal works fine (and in fact starts much faster then the previous version).

Doing this didn't help:

```
xhost +localhost
xhost +<my-user>
```

Neither did this:

```
chroot -R root:root /opt/eclipse
chroot -R my-group:my-user /opt/eclipse
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

EDIT: curiously, unpacking it again, this time under my home dir didn't help  either. Showing that giving up does not help much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how helpful this is, but that kind of error message happens when the DISPLAY is not set properly: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314849.

If your display is set, I'm not sure where to go from here since you've already done xhost +...

Comment: gosh, who could believe it was that simple!... You are absolutely right. A few days ago I played with DISPLAY on that window and completely forgot. Works like a charm now. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the problem, I was assuming that the DISPLAY I specified is correct, but after reading your post, I double checked and found that it was wrong.

Comment: @davka How did you get to fix this exactly? I tried setting `DISPLAY` to `local_host:0.0` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @AymanSalah I don't remember already :) but perhaps try `localhost` without the underscore. Test if it is defined in your system e.g. `ping localhost`

Comment: @davka My bad! nice pointing out that. Issue still persists though. With it set to `localhost:0.0`, I cant even launch `gedit` I get this error `(gedit:28250): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:0.0`.